# subscribing to observables to update viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, refresh, viewmodel

http://jsfiddle.net/tim3046/jtmY3/2/

---

I got the observables to partly work since it updates the top par string.

This is what im subscribing to so im wondering if maybe this part is wrong since when i add a golfer it has the currently selected course par. (ie) I can have 2 golfers on one course and 3 on another so when the radio button is hit the only thing its doing is changing the par for the next golfer to be added.

```
self.site.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    var len = self.golfers().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        self.golfers()[i].par(self.availableCourses()[self.site()].courseP);
    }
});
```

and here is where i have my available courses

```
self.availableCourses = ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable("Fort Cherry Golf Club"),
            courseP: [ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(5), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(4),
            ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(4),
            ko.observable(5), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4)]
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Lake View Golf Course"),
            courseP: [ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(5), ko.observable(4),
            ko.observable(5), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(4),
            ko.observable(5), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(3), ko.observable(4), ko.observable(5)]
        }
            ]);
```

Comment: That is way too much code to wade through. Please boil it down to the relevant elements.

Comment: Im not sure what i can take out and what i cant because its all needed for it to work properly. Basically what im trying to do is subscribe to my view model to detect and changes and then refresh it. Heres an example i found that is doing something like what i want but uses viewModel as a variable rather than a function

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/TTGbH/

Answer (score -1):

With knockout you create observables in your view model to represent the state of the UI.  Then you can subscribe to changes in those observables if you need to.  See the very bottom of the [KO page about observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

I set up a simple fiddle to demonstrate the basics of using the subscribe function on observables:

http://jsfiddle.net/YRscs/1/

Comment: I got the subscription to work, when it fires is there a way to refresh the view model? I have observablesArrays that are all computed off of eachother and when i change one of them im trying to get the others to update as well.

Comment: When you viewmodel changes, you are subscribing to it. So why would you then want to refresh it if it just changed? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I know its a lot of code but if you run it and hit the radio buttons you can see what im trying to do. Basically im trying to switch between two golf courses that have different pars. Once the par changes i want the first function caller Golfer to run through again and update the data to reflect the new course par. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tim3046/jtmY3/2/

Comment: @user1515742 KO should take care of automatically updating your dependent observables whenever you update one of the dependencies.  I'm guessing that somewhere in your code you're trying to set an observable using = instead of calling its 'setter' function.  That is, I suspect your doing viewModel.observable = value; instead of viewModel.observable( value );

Comment: I checked but couldnt find any, I am using computed functions where i take each element of the array and put it into a variable to keep a count until the end. Then i return the count, for example i have `this.OUT = ko.computed(function () { return addSides(golfer.holes, 0, 8); });` for each score type. Could that maybe be it?

Comment: How about this line in your updatePar() function: vm.golfers()[i].par = vm.availableCourses()[vm.site()].courseP;  If I'm reading this correctly, vm.golfers()[i].par is an observableArray.  observableArrays also need to have their values set using the setter function syntax.  So I think it should be vm.golfers()[i].par( vm.availableCourses()[vm.site()].courseP );

Comment: Whoops i forgot to edit my original post, I noticed that and changed it to subscribe to my radio button values in the updated one in the comments. In the updated version the par updates with the radio button but nothing else updates with it